# Read as bytes/binary from Oracle using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to read data from Oracle using pyspark. Since the encoding of the source data is unknown reading it as a string forces UTF-8 encoding which results in having REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. (EF BF BD in hex).

I would like to read the contents from Oracle as binary/bytes to avoid this forceful encoding.

My sample data in hex and the problematic character is highlighted which is forcefully converted with replacement character.

> 43,4f,52,41,20,52,45,48,41,42,49,4c,49,54,41,54,49,4f,4e,20,43,4c,49,4e,49,43,20,**e2,80,93**,20,4e,4f,52,54,48,20,54,41,4d,50,41,20,28,43,4f,52,41,20,48,45,41,4c,54,48,20,53,45,52,56,49,43,45,53,20,49,4e,43,29

The way am trying to read from Oracle

```
testDF = spark.read \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
            .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + 'host' + ".athenahealth.com:1521/" + 'instance') \
            .option("dbtable", sqlstring) \
            .option("user", 'username') \
            .option("password", 'passwd') \
            .load()
```

The way am checking the dataframe contains the replacement character to confirm that the manipulation happens on reading from Oracle.

> testDF.withColumn("hexdump", f.hex("NAME")).show(truncate=False)

Please advise if there is any way to stop this force encoding while reading from Oracle.

Comment: "... the encoding of the source data is unknown" - I would suggest: try to find it out.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The problem is, it contains mixed encoding some data have UTF-8 and some have ISO-8859-1 and thats why i wanted to read as binary without any force encoding

Comment: Is it an option to covert the input data before you load it?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The data to Oracle comes from variety of sources so converting during the load is not an option for me thats why am trying to avoid it while reading from Oracle